# bootstrap thumbnail gallery - moving col-md-3 from one position to another

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a container class and within that div i have 4 cols

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

and 2 seperate arrows for left and right

[image: just like this]

In the image the far right div is not shows but when I press the left button I would like all divs to move one item to the left (the far right div is removed) and when I press the right button I would like all divs to move one spot to the right except the far right div that would appear as the first div on the right. There could be more then 4 divs.

Can use css and or jquery

I have this peice of code that moves 3 cols together

```
        <div class="container">

            <div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
             <div class="carousel-inner">
               <div class="item active">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-E8GdZQshD7I/WI1-yGMXseI/AAAAAAAACfs/ZndWplkyLpgVPO5IQ294pjxr9rq8YtqcwCLcB/s640/boot1.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hmUAa7DH5N4/WI2KJqMdhrI/AAAAAAAACf8/huv-RB55G_QpCI-9G-iA0JrS1pqCswEogCLcB/s640/boot2.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZWboxYj_gz0/WInKMMQA_HI/AAAAAAAACe4/4ihHdvifuKYJNQElLULtivsCne9ZDbM3ACLcB/s640/di.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="item">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-hmUAa7DH5N4/WI2KJqMdhrI/AAAAAAAACf8/huv-RB55G_QpCI-9G-iA0JrS1pqCswEogCLcB/s640/boot2.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZWboxYj_gz0/WInKMMQA_HI/AAAAAAAACe4/4ihHdvifuKYJNQElLULtivsCne9ZDbM3ACLcB/s640/di.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-E8GdZQshD7I/WI1-yGMXseI/AAAAAAAACfs/ZndWplkyLpgVPO5IQ294pjxr9rq8YtqcwCLcB/s640/boot1.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="item">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-E8GdZQshD7I/WI1-yGMXseI/AAAAAAAACfs/ZndWplkyLpgVPO5IQ294pjxr9rq8YtqcwCLcB/s640/boot2.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-E8GdZQshD7I/WI1-yGMXseI/AAAAAAAACfs/ZndWplkyLpgVPO5IQ294pjxr9rq8YtqcwCLcB/s640/boot1.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                     <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZWboxYj_gz0/WInKMMQA_HI/AAAAAAAACe4/4ihHdvifuKYJNQElLULtivsCne9ZDbM3ACLcB/s640/di.png" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
              </div>
              <a class="left carousel-control" href="#imageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#imageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
             </div>

        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow is not a code writing service and some effort is expected.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you planning to use a 3rd party slider? You need to provide more of your work so people can help you, not do your work for you.

Comment: What i plan to  is forgo animation and play with display visible and hide of 3 of n divs. Just thought that maybe there was some bootstrap css magic allready set in place. I prefer not to use a third party plugin because the gallery is but a small part of a landing page system that has to be pixel perfect.